# Can't import 'UseSelector' from react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[image]
When i try to import 'useSelector', there is an error in the console "useSelector is not exported from react-redux"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of react-redux

Comment: I installed react-redux yesterday, so i think it should be the latest version